# using vectors in C++ gives me an error that I cannot make any sense of

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>


float comp_cur(float A_x, float A_y, float B_x, float B_y, float C_x, float C_y);
void comp_arr(std::vector<float> vals, std::vector<float> out, int scale, float dim);

main(){
    std::vector <float> curves;
    std::vector <float> inputs;

    inputs.push_back(2.0);
    inputs.push_back(3.0);
    inputs.push_back(6.0);
    inputs.push_back(1.0);
    inputs.push_back(7.0);

    comp_arr(inputs,curves,1.0,1.0);
}

float comp_cur(float A_x, float A_y, float B_x, float B_y, float C_x, float C_y){

    B_x = B_x-A_x;
    B_y = B_y-A_y;
    C_x = C_x-A_x;
    C_y = C_y-A_y;
    A_x = 0;
    A_y = 0;

    float numerator_A = C_y*B_x - B_y*C_x;
    float denominator_A = C_x*C_x*B_x - C_x*B_x*B_x;
    float A = numerator_A / denominator_A;

    float B = (B_y - A*B_x*B_x) / B_x;

    float curviture = 2*A / powf( (1 + (2*A*B_x + B)*(2*A*B_x + B)), 1.5);
    return (curviture);
}

void comp_arr(std::vector<float> vals, std::vector<float> out, int scale, float dim){
    for(int i = scale; i < sizeof(vals)-scale+1; i++){
        float cur = comp_cur((i-scale)*dim, vals[i-1], i*dim, vals[i], (i+scale)*dim, vals[i+1]);
        out.push_back(cur);
    }
}
```

Everything about comp_cur works fine, but the comp_arr function is throwing a hideous error. I'm pretty new to C and C++ so I can't make any sense of this error at all.

```
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `main':
comp.cpp:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o:(.ARM.extab+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::~vector()':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEED2Ev[_ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEED5Ev]+0x6c): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEED2Ev[_ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEED5Ev]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::vector(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&)':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEEC2ERKS1_[_ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEEC5ERKS1_]+0xb4): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEEC2ERKS1_[_ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEEC5ERKS1_]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::~_Vector_base()':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEED2Ev[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEED5Ev]+0x70): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEED2Ev[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEED5Ev]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, float const&)':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPfS1_EERKf[std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<    float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, float const&)]+0x290): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPfS1_EERKf[std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<    float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, float const&)]+0x294): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPfS1_EERKf[std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<    float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, float const&)]+0x2a0): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPfS1_EERKf[std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<    float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, float const&)]+0x308): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt6vectorIfSaIfEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPfS1_EERKf[std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>     >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, float const&)]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::_Vector_base(unsigned int, std::allocator<float> const&)':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEEC2EjRKS0_[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEEC5EjRKS0_]+0x90): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEEC2EjRKS0_[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIfSaIfEEC5EjRKS0_]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_check_len(unsigned int, char const*) const':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIfSaIfEE12_M_check_lenEjPKc[std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_check_len(unsigned int, char const*) const]+0x54): undefined reference to     `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::deallocate(float*, unsigned int)':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIfE10deallocateEPfj[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::deallocate(float*, unsigned int)]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccTCZ2bX.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
comp.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIfE8allocateEjPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x40): undefined reference to     `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
comp.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIfE8allocateEjPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x50): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned     int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Looks like your linking step isn't linking with the C++ standard library.

Comment: It seems you are using pass-by-value. Either pass per reference or use pointers. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: please give the full command line. And, yes, pass the `vector`s by reference (`std::vector<float> const&vals` etc in the argument list to `comp_arr`)

Comment: @bash.d the vectors are going out of scope immediately so they could be moved.

Comment: Please show how you are compiling. If it's a simple command, show that. If it's a makefile, show that.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie I should be going to bed...

Comment: I used the command "gcc comp.cpp -lm -o comp"

Comment: In your `comp_arr()` function the expression `sizeof(vals)` is almost certainly not what you want. If you want to know the number of elements in the vector use `vals.size()` instead.

Comment: @tmathmeyer - Following the excellent advice in @sftrabbit's answer, do `g++ comp.cpp -lm -o comp` instead.

Comment: that got it to compile, however now the vector "curves" has nothing in it

Comment: @tmathmeyer That's a separate question entirely but I'll try to help. When you pass `curves` to `comp_arr`, you are passing it by value (the argument type is `std::vector<float>`) - this *copies* it. You then start putting stuff in that copy and it has no effect on `curves`. If you want to make sure there is no copy, you need to pass by reference. Change the argument type to `std::vector<float>&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take an educated guess without knowing how you're compiling.

Make sure you compile with `g++` rather than `gcc` - `g++` automatically sets up some options for compiling c++ for you, including linking to the standard library. Alternatively, give the `-lstdc++` and `-x c++` options.